# Combinatorial loop of SR latch

Tags: latch, ise

I implemented an SR latch in Verilog.

```
module sr_latch(
    output Q,
    output P,
    input S,
    input R
);

nor(P, S, Q);
nor(Q, R, P);

endmodule
```

However, Xilinx ISE reports a warning:

```
WARNING:Xst:2170 - Unit sr_latch : the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop: n0000.
```

Is this warning avoidable for implementing an SR latch?

Should I just ignore it?

Comment: No you can't. FPGAs are not meant for implementing latches in RTL. They have to be properly timed due to the combi feedback, which FPGA timing analysers can't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem avoidable. Even in [this document](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/university/Vivado-Teaching/HDL-Design/2013x/Nexys4/Verilog/docs-pdf/lab5.pdf) by Xilinx themselves they use this Verilog code to generate an SR-latch

```
module SR_latch_gate (input R, input S, output Q, output Qbar);
      nor (Q, R, Qbar);
      nor (Qbar, S, Q);
endmodule

module SR_latch_dataflow (input R, input S, output Q, output Qbar);
      assign #2 Q_i = Q;
      assign #2 Qbar_i = Qbar;
      assign #2 Q = ~ (R | Qbar);
      assign #2 Qbar = ~ (S | Q);
endmodule
```

which returns this warning when synthesizing (I couldn't recreate the warning you show in your question)

> Critical Warning: 1 LUT cells form a combinatorial loop. This can create a race condition. Timing analysis may not be accurate. The preferred resolution is to modify the design to remove combinatorial logic loops.